# I want to read in a dictionary in a redefined function

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to change the way that my function reads in code, so that I can import a class with easier managed variables.

I have all the libraries I want to edit already imported.

```
class http_request(object):

  def __init__(self, website_address, valuedictionary):
   self.website_address = website_address
   self.valuedictionary = valuedictionary

  def get(self):
    return requests.get(website_address, params=valuedictionary)

  def post(self):
    return requests.post(website_address, data=valuedictionary)

def postContext(self):
    return requests.post(website_address, data=valuedictionary).context  
def getContext(self):
    return requests.get(website_address, params=valuedictionary).context

htay = http_request(web_add, payload)

print str(htay.postContext)
```

I am getting this as my response:
"bound method http_request.get of <**main**.http_request object at 0x8735cec>>"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you wanted to call the method:

```
print str(htay.postContext())
#                         ^^ Need parenthesis to call a method
```

Of course, this will probably give you an error about a `global website_address not defined` or something of the like because within the method, you need to get the instance attribute via `self`:

```
def postContext(self):
    return requests.post(self.website_address, data=self.valuedictionary).context
```

And you'll need to make the analogous change in your other methods as well.

Comment: Yes, my bad. However now when this happens I receive "NameError: global name 'website_address' is not defined"

Comment: @user1999976 -- I'm a few steps ahead of you -- check my edit.